# Trouble with fs.createReadStream

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having some trouble executing the following code (taken from [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_events.asp)) on my computer:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var rs = fs.createReadStream('./demofile.txt');
rs.on('open', function () {
  console.log('The file is open');
});
```

The particular errors I receive when I try to execute this file are as follows:

```
    Nathans-MacBook-Pro-2:meeting-sums-writer nathan$ node myfirst.js
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './demofile.txt'
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
    at internal/fs/streams.js:147:14
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:171:23) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: './demofile.txt'
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated here! I am afraid that I have fudged up somewhere along the way with the installation and setup of my computer with all of these things...

Comment: Please don't use or link to w3schools. Anyway, because that page isn't about reading a file but events, and not a tutorial but merely example code, that piece of code won't work unless there's an actual file called `demofile.txt` in the same folder as your script. The error message is telling you exactly that: you're trying to read a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

Read the error! It says

> "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './demofile.txt'"

, which means there is no demofile.txt file, first try making a demofile.txt in your program directory and then run the program

Comment: You can also put `console.log(__dirname)` in your code to see what the working directory is at runtime. And do `console.log(fs.readdirSync(__dirname))` to see what files are in that directory. #debugging

Comment: use console.log(__dirname) as suggested by @Josh Wulf. This would print out your current directory. then append the path to the file you want to read

Comment: use console.log(__dirname) as suggested by @Josh Wulf. This would print out your current directory. then append the path to the file you want to read